# Suggested edit queue size drops to 0 randomly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits

After getting impatient with a few of my edits, I noticed something odd:
[image: Suggested Edits queue (0 edits)]
This was taken within the same *minute* as this screenshot:
[image: I have 4 pending edits]
WTF is going on? Especially given that a few minutes after them, the queue size jumped *back up* to a hundred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have nearly enough rep to review suggested edits, anywhere.

You can *suggest* edits of course, but you can't review them. That requires other people with at least 2K rep.

The count is cached, and excludes edits currently being reviewed.

Comment: The count probably also excludes edits you wouldn't be able to review because you suggested them yourself.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why would it just drop to 0 out of nowhere and then spring back to 100 five minutes later?

Comment: There are a lot of users that can and do robo-review suggested edits @SomePerson

Comment: So, there's a 5-minute expiration on the soft "locks" that are put in place when someone starts reviewing an edit, @SomePerson. If a large number of people are reviewing, that could easily lead to big variations in the number of available tasks to review.